# How to configure withMaven within one pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline

I try to execute multiple stages within a jenkins pipeline with maven. In the moment every step within the steps block within a stage is wrapped with `withMaven( ... )`. The needed mavenOpts and the local maven repo stays the same throughout the whole jenkins pipeline, so I wondered if it's possible to configure the maven pipeline integration plugin at the beginning of this pipeline so I don't need to wrap every single step with the same `withMaven()` wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a shared-library method that accepts a string, and performs a withMaven upon it.  Then, from the Jenkinsfile, invoke the shared-library method from each step that needs it.  That will encapsulate a bunch of maven-configuration stuff inside the centralized shared-lib.

Comment: Thank you very much, that would work that's right. But not what I'm really looking for...